# Microphone fitlered through pulseeffects not being regonized on Zoom

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, gentoo, zoom

I am using pulseeffects on my microphone inputs to filter my voice a bit. It's working in every other application that supports pulseaudio except Zoom.

Zoom seems my microphone, but it just ignores pulseeffects completely. Pulseeffects,also, doesn't show any bars or anything indicating that something is using the microphone. However, the application shows up in pulseeffects.
[image]

Then, I have these very weird options in "Speaker" for Zoom "PulseEffects(apps)" and "PulseEffects(mic)." Which, don't appear in Microphone.

[image]

How do I get Zoom to recognize pulseeffects?